# "This is a song by Lady Gaga" or "this is the song by Lady Gaga"?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

Which article is appropriate in the blank below, *a* or *the*?

> — What are you singing? I've heard the song many times.
>   — This is *_*_ song by Lady Gaga.

Comment: You might be interested in our sister site specifically for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2), which is about to get created. Feel free to commit and post. Thank you.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Why this or that? What are you singing? *It is a song by Lady Gaga.*?

Answer (score 1):

Either one can be used, depending on what you are trying to say.

I'd probably use the word "the" only if I was talking about Lada Gaga's latest hit, one that was getting a lot of airplay on the radio. That would be a shortened way of saying:

> This is the song by Lady Gaga [you've been hearing every day on the radio].

If it was one of her former hits, though, like *Poker Face* or *Bad Romance*, then I'd almost certainly use *a* instead of *the*.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.
Your explanation is very understandable.

Comment: I agree with your answer, J.R., but without that parenthetical addition, which the OP didn't give as an option, the "the" version wouldn't be right, of course.

Comment: @KristinaLopez: Context is everything, which is what I wanted to emphasize. Far too many of these "which one is right" questions fail to account for the fact that, oftentimes, the "wrong" answer is the "right" answer – under the right circumstances. The O.P. may not have given that as an option (as you said), but the O.P. didn't exclude that condition, either.

Comment: As I find to be true so often, you're right! Context is everything! :-)

Answer (score -1):

I’m not even sure you need to worry about whether it should be *the song, that song or this song.* I think I would simply use this:

> What are you singing? I've heard it many times.
>
> It’s a song by Lady Gaga, *or simply*
>
> A song by Lady Gaga.